# .net chart control: retain series colors when adding and removing other series?

Tags: c#, .net, charts

When adding and removing series from a .net chart control (line chart), how can I retain the existing series colors?

Currently, when I add several series to a chart, they all get colors assigned automatically from the chart palette.  But if I then remove the first series, the colors of all of the subsequent series get reset according to the order in the chart palette.  Is there any way to stop this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just set the chart colors directly and not use a Palette?

```
Chart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None;
Chart.Series[0].Color = Color.Green;
```

etc, etc. This does mean you have to set the color for each series as you add it, but c'est la vie.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to call `ApplyPaletteColors` to break the automatic coloring scheme.

Then you can apply each series its very own palette color and it will stick:

```
chart1.ApplyPaletteColors();
series1.Color = series1.Color;
series2.Color = series2.Color;
// or, of course..:    
series1.Color = someColor;
series2.Color = someOtherColor;
..
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you add all the series that the chart will use when setting up the chart and then enable or disable the series as you want them shown, it will retain the same colors that were assigned to the series.
I imagine the issue you are running into is actually removing the series from the chart and then adding it back in later as a new series (which I believe is causing it to take the next color in the palette).

In my chart I am working on now, I actually added check boxes to control if series were enabled are disabled and it has been keeping the same color for all the series.

```
// Assuming I have chart set up with chart area and 3 series.
chart.Series.Add(s1);
chart.Series.Add(s2);
chart.Series.Add(s3);

CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
cb1.Text = s1.Name;
cb.Checked = s1.Enabled;
// Set up action for when checkbox is changed.
cb.CheckedChanged += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  // Set series enabled property based on check box Checked property
  s1.Enabled = cb.Checked;
  // Will recalculate the scale to show the remaining series better.
  // If you do not want to adjust chart size for remaining series,
  // this can be removed.
  chart.ChartAreas[s1.ChartArea].RecalculateAxesScale();
  // Force redraw of chart area
  chart.Invalidate();
};
this.Controls.Add(cb1);

// Repeat for additional check boxes and add to UI
```

I hope this helps if someone runs across this later.